# neither nor comma

Tags: grammar

I just read a sentence that was correct like that:

**I like neither tomatoes, nor broccoli.**

but also correct like that:

**I like neither broccoli nor tomatoes.**

However, if I typed:

**I like neither broccoli, nor tomatoes.**

It would be incorrect. Can anyone explain me why is that?

Comment: What is the difference between your "correct" first sentence and your "incorrect" third sentence? Apart from the order of the foods, they appear identical to me. Why is the broccoli-first sentence apparently incorrect? Who says so?

Comment: Quill.com is were it marked me this answer as incorrect. The incorrection was claimed to be the comma between broccoli and tomatoes, however if it were tomatoes and broccoli the comma was correct.

Comment: I am sure you mean quill.org. Domain name aside, the order of food should not matter. If it does in a particular website, it is surely a fault. Also putting a comma is optional in my opinion.

Comment: @satnam Thanks for the advice, however I'd like to know, should I use comma between those two or not?

Comment: You need to add the reference for the claim, so that members may judge (1) the accuracy of the above; (2) the likelihood that the authors have a reasonable command of English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) 'Neither' and 'Nor' are a pair of correlative conjunctions (other examples, either...or, not only...but also). When pairs of such conjunctions are used in a sentence, a comma to separate them is not required. Hence, your sentence without a comma is correct. Note that there is an exception to this rule. For example, if commas are required to offset a nonrestrictive clause, then they must be retained.
For example:
Neither John, who was ill, nor Oliver attended the party.

2) The word 'Neither' indicates that two ideas are linked together in a sentence. Hence, to link the two ideas in your sentence (you don't like broccoli *and* you also don't like tomatoes) comma must be removed.

Hope I was able to explain it in a simplified way. Best Regards!

Comment: 'The comma is not required' or 'the comma should not be used'? Can you also supply supporting evidence, please?